# Please help me to optimize the below mentioned script as the same table(i.e. Incident_Audit_log) has utilized multiple times?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, query-tuning

```
select  A.*           
from Incident_Audit_log a  where incident_audit_log_id in     
(select top 1 incident_audit_log_id from Incident_Audit_log b 
where  b.incident_id=a.incident_id and  b.status_did=a.status_did    
and b.tracking_code_did = (select tracking_code_did     
from Incident_Audit_log where update_date = (select MAX(update_date)     
from Incident_Audit_log where Status_did in (103, 1035)    
and incident_id = b.incident_id)    
and incident_id = b.incident_id)    
order by update_date asc)
```

Comment: What do you want to select? How does table looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve but I guess that you want to extract row with new newest update and status_did equal to 13 and 1035.

In that case this should work:

```
select  *
from    (
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY update_date DESC) AS rn, 
           *
        from    Incident_Audit_log
        where status_did in (103, 1035)
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

In case not , provide more info.